# Preview Columns in DataFrame with dplyr select

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Is there anyway to preview a dataframes columns names when using `dplyr` `select` function?
I would like to be able to obtain something in the spirit of using the `$` in base R, which previews the names of objects in a data frame.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to type a partial name and hit the "Tab" key.  It will either autocomplete or show you a possible list.  Note I am using R 3.5.1 with RStudio 1.1.

Comment: It does not recognize the data frame column names, if I understand correctly.